# How to stop GCP vm instances using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I am new to Terraform. How to stop GCP vm instances using terraform?
I have tried changing status of the vm instance, it's available for AWS but couldn't find the way to do it for GCP.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit

Since [version `v3.11.0` of Google provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/v3.11.0/CHANGELOG.md#3110-march-02-2020) (released 2020/03/02), it is possible to shutdown and start a Compute instance with `desired_status` field :

> - compute: added the ability to manage the status of google_compute_instance resources with the desired_status field

Just declare in your Terraform resource :

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "test"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  [...]

  desired_status = "TERMINATED"
}
```

And apply your changes. If your instance was running before, it should be shut down. [This PR](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/pull/4797) shows the modifications that have been added, if you are interested to take a look. The `desired_status` can either take `RUNNING` or `TERMINATED` values.

#### Previous answer (as of 2019/10/26)

As of the time of the question (2019/09/18), with the latest Google provider available then (version `v2.15.0`), this is not possible to update the status of a Google Compute instance.

The following issue is opened on the [Google Terraform provider on Github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google) :

- [google_compute_instance should allow to specify instance state #1719](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1719)

There is also a Pull Request to add this feature :

- [ability to change instance_state #2956](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/pull/2956)

But unfortunately, this PR seems to be stale (not updated since 2019/03/13).

Comment: doesn't really work: "An argument named "desired_status" is not expected here", gcp provider >3.5

Comment: @Xao Please use the latest provider. 3.5 is too old. `desired_status` field have been introduced in 3.11.0.

Comment: Can confirm this works for me via version 3.1.2.
Also, desired_status="TERMINATED" is equivalent to "stopped" in GCP lingo.

Comment: @Jamaica-Jan do you mean 3.12.0? :) `desired_status` appeared only in 3.11.0.